# How to open and read a text file manually copied to download folder on Android 13

Tags: android, permissions, storage-access-framework

I just updated to a new tablet running Android 13, and now my app can no longer open a text file that is manually copied to the /Download folder.  Previously had been requesting READ and WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE, but now even with those permissions now get IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).  It has been a requirement for my app to open a specifically named text file (route.txt) that a customer copies to the /Download folder, and then copy the contents to a String var.  Has Google now inhibited what has been allowed for over a decade?  It will be a major nightmare to have to inform 20K+ users that their business logic must change :(

Have tried checking, and requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (if not granted).  Once granted, then try to open the file (read to a String)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Even with permissions granted, I get the EACCES error when trying to open the file:

```
   static String readRouteFile(String sFile){
        Log.d(TAG, "readRouteFile(" + sFile + ")");

        File f = new File(sFile);

        if(f.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "readRouteFile.exists");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            FileInputStream fis;
            String sbuf;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                while ((sbuf = bReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    sb.append(sbuf).append('\n');
                }

                bReader.close();
                fis.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "readRouteFile.size:" + sb.length());
                return sb.toString();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "readRouteFile.IOException:" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "readRouteFile.!exist:" + sFile);
        }

        return null;
    }//readRouteFile
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` from the Storage Access Framework and let the user choose the file to open. Then, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content. "Has Google now inhibited what has been allowed for over a decade?" -- it has been "inhibited" since Android 11, and the recommended alternative (Storage Access Framework) has been around since Android 4.4.

Comment: The app does the open and read in the background - and is not intended for user selection - filename being checked for is always named route.txt.  If the app finds this file at startup, it is a trigger that controls how the app will behave - by parsing the contents of the file.  The main concern from the customers has always been simplicity - they wanted a simple solution for sending a flat file to the Android device, and then have our app (at startup) search for this file.  Ok for 9 years - Just looking for any feedback that might reveal something I missed that can continue this project.

Comment: You no longer have access to `Downloads/`, as of Android 11, except for files that your app places there itself, unless you use the Storage Access Framework. I think you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and ask the user to give you access to all of `Downloads/`. You can wrap the resulting `Uri` in `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` and use that to access your file. And, you can use `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` to have long-term access to that tree for your background operations.

Comment: So, this would require each of our customers, to have each of their end users (20k+ so far) to perform a new staging operation for every device - that's quite unfortunate as the majority of the user base is not well versed on steps as described, nor would our customer base take kindly to having to enforce such a requirement to their legacy fleet of drivers.  But, I get it, another decision made from above, to change how Android accesses such dangerous things like a simple text file from being read.  I sure wish there was a truly public landing space without restrictions - like TEMP.

Comment: Thank you #CommonsWare, for taking the time to share the above potential solution -